# Makefile ifneq returning false even when two strings are clearly different

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to make a simple configuration in a `Makefile` to have it enable/disable a `DEBUG` flag to follow if the user uses either `-d` or `--debug=...` when calling `make`.

This seems to make sense to me, but for some reason the first `ifneq` conditional is not working. It always returns false, regardless of what is inputted. If I simply `echo` out the `$(findstring --debug,-$(MAKEFLAGS))` command in the target, I get the expected `--debug` I'm looking for... so I'm confident that function is returning the string, as expected.

So why is the `neq` conditional check of `--debug` against an empty string returning `false`?

```
# By default, the `DEBUG` flag will follow whether the `make` command was called with the `-d` or `--debug` s:
#
# `make -d`
# `make --debug=basic`
#
# To enable this `DEBUG` flag without increasing `make` verbosity, set the flag manually:
#
# `make DEBUG=1`
#
ifneq (,$(findstring --debug,-$(MAKEFLAGS)))
DEBUG ?= 1
endif

ifneq (,$(findstring d,-$(filter-out --%,-$(MAKEFLAGS))))
DEBUG ?= 1
endif

DEBUG ?= 0
```

```
make                # Works as expected
make -d             # Works as expected
make --debug=basic  # Does not work
```

Comment: I get different results; neither of your attempts seems to work, at least strictly speaking. https://ideone.com/gjUlfq

Comment: @tripleee thanks - although, if I'm reading that tool correctly, it is the same?  the first `make` outputs `0` (expected); the second `make --debug=basic` outputs `0` (same problem I have); and the third `make -d` outputs `1` - exactly as I described.... unless I'm missing something? quotes also don't work

Comment: Why don't use use `$(info ...)` to show the value of `$(MAKEFLAGS)`?  Occam's razor says the problem is that the content of that variable is not what you expect, rather than a basic feature like `ifneq` not working.

Comment: @MadScientist thanks, I've definitely done that. not only does it show what's expected, if I do a comparison in anything except a conditional, it works as expected.For example, `echo $(findstring --debug,-$(MAKEFLAGS))` will output `--debug`, which is why it almost seems like the `ifneq` is failing.  If you take that, it's like saying `ifneq (,--debug) == false` which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your behavior, using GNU Make 4.4.1 on GNU/Linux.  Please specify which version of GNU Make you're using, and on which platform (where you got your build of GNU Make from).

Here's what I see:

```
$ cat Makefile
$(info MAKEFLAGS = '$(MAKEFLAGS)')

ifneq (,$(findstring --debug,-$(MAKEFLAGS)))
DEBUG ?= 1
$(info matches --debug)
endif

ifneq (,$(findstring d,-$(filter-out --%,-$(MAKEFLAGS))))
DEBUG ?= 1
$(info matches -d)
endif

DEBUG ?= 0
$(info DEBUG = $(DEBUG))
```

Then:

```
$ make -rR
MAKEFLAGS = 'rR'
DEBUG = 0
make: *** No targets.  Stop.

$ make -rR -d
  ...
MAKEFLAGS = 'drR'
matches -d
DEBUG = 1

$ make -rR --debug=basic
  ...
MAKEFLAGS = 'rR --debug=basic'
matches --debug
DEBUG = 1
```

Just to note, this:

```
$(findstring d,-$(filter-out --%,-$(MAKEFLAGS))))
```

is more reliably / straightforwardly written:

```
$(findstring d,$(firstword -$(MAKEFLAGS)))
```

Comment: Thank you - maybe that's the issue?  `GNU Make 3.81 -- This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0`.  Is macOS make just super outdated?

Comment: This was 100% it - I used homebrew to install a later version and it fixed it wonderfully. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, yeah.  Well first, the version of GNU Make that is provided by Apple has some known bugs, even beyond what was in the official GNU release of GNU Make 3.81.  But second, MAKEFLAGS didn't have all the options in it when the makefile was parsed until GNU Make 4.4.  MAKEFLAGS is technically supposed to be used for a parent make to communicate options to its sub-make so it didn't get filled in until GNU Make was running recipes, after all makefiles had been parsed.  In newer versions that changed so it's set earlier.

Comment: Yeah, you've got it - when I installed `make` via homebrew, I didn't realize that the binary was installed as `gmake` not replacing `make`. An alias made quick work of that. Thanks again!